# The woes of endless columns in .csv data in R

Tags: r, csv

So I have a bunch of .csv files that were output by a simulation. I'm writing an R script to run through them and make a histogram of a column in each .csv file. However, the .csv is written in such a way that R does not like it. When I was testing it, I had been originally opening the files in Excel and apparently this changed the format to one R liked. Then when I went back to run the script on the entire folder I discovered that R doesn't like the format.
I was reading the data in as:

```
x <- read.csv("synch-imit-characteristics-2-tags-2-size-200-cost-0.1run-2-.csv", strip.white=TRUE)

Error in read.table(test, strip.white = TRUE, header = TRUE) : 
  more columns than column names
```

Investigating I found that the original .csv file, which R does not like, looks different than after the test one I opened with excel. I copied and pasted the first bit below after opening it in notepad:

```
cost,0.1

mean-loyalty, mean-hospitality

0.9885449527316088, 0.33240076252915735

weight,1 of p1, 2 of p1,
```

However, in notepad, there is no apparent formatting. In fact, between rows there is no space at all, ie it is cost,0.1mean-loyalty,mean-hospitality0.988544, etc. So it is weird to me as well that when I cope and paste it from notepad it gets the desired formatting as above. Anyway, moving on, after I had opened it in excel it got transferred to this"

```
cost,0.1,,,,,,,,

mean-loyalty, mean-hospitality,,,,,,,,

0.989771257,0.335847092,,,,,,,,

weight,1 of p1, etc...
```

So it seems like the data originally has no separation between rows (but I don't know how excel figures it out, or copying and pasting it) but R doesn't pick up on this. Instead, it views it all as one row (and since I have 40,000+ rows, it doesn't have that many columns). I don't want to have to open and save every file in excel. Is there a way to get R to read the data as desired?

Since when I copy and paste it from notepad it had new lines for the rows, it seems like I just need R to read it knowing that commas separate columns on the same row and a return separates rows. I tried messing around with all the sep="" commands I could find. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help without one of the (un-modified, unopened in Excel) files. Could you provide a link to one somehow?

Comment: does `header=F` work?

Comment: What is your R version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To first solve the Notepad issue:

You must have CR (carriage return, `\r`) characters between the lines (and no LF, \n characters, causing Notepad to see it as one line).
Some programs accept this as well as a new line character, some don't.

You can for example use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to replace all '\r' with '\n' or '\r\n', using Replace wih the "Extended" option. First select View > Show Symbol > Show all characters, so see what you are doing.

#### Finally, to get back to R:

(As it was pointed out, R can actually handle CR as a newline)

read.csv assumes that you have non-empty header names in the first row, but instead you have:

```
cost,0.1
```

while later in the data you have a row with more than just two columns:

```
weight,1 of p1, 2 of p1,
```

This means that not all columns have a header name (and I wonder if 0.1 was supposed to be a header name anyway).

The two solutions can be:

1. add a header including all columns, or
2. as it was pointed out in a comment use `header=F`.

Comment: R accepts either '\n' or '\r\n' as valid line terminators. I would be surprised if this turned out to be the answer. See the help page for `scan`

Comment: You are right: this is only the answer to the Notepad part and otherwise the headers aer missing. I'll amend my answer.